# ag-grid popup cellEditor - how to prevent close on click?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid popup cellEditor which contains an angular mat-select control. Is there a way to prevent the popup cell editor default behavior of closing on a click outside the cell? When an item is selected the ag-grid popup cellEditor closes. I believe this is due to the click on the select drop down being interpreted as outside the cell. Is it possible to prevent popup cell closure for this case or even in all cases such that I can control it completely via code using gridApi.stopEditing()?

See https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview for information on the select control. I am not including full details here as it is likely not important.

Comment: provide a plunk or stackblitz - to play around and provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

[Image of popup editor, You can see how cell is before editor is invoked as well.  See where the blue number one appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y089Y.png)